# Creating a plot for a solid (torus)

Tags: plotting, graphics

We have the following two equations: Sqrt[1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2], -Sqrt[1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2] and these have to be plotted into a parametricplot3D and regionplot3D, and these would yield an image of a torus.

For regionplot3D, I've tried doing the following:

```
RegionPlot3D[{z^2 > Sqrt[1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)],z^2 < Sqrt[1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]
```

but no graph appears. I only get a graph when I start decreasing the x, y, z ranges but it doesn't look like a torus.
As for the parametricplot3D, I know that to get a torus shape I can use the following

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[
2 Pi u], (2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], Sin[2 Pi v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

but I'm not sure if those are the right equations to use, in order to get a torus that is similar to the one the original equations would give when plotted using plot3D. So, my question is, how can I get a torus using regionplot3D and parametricplot3D for the above equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right equation should be as below.

```
ImplicitRegion[
  z^2 <= 1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2, {x, y, z}] // Region
```

Or

```
RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[z^2 <= 1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2, {x, y, z}], 
 PlotPoints -> 80]
```

Or

```
RegionPlot3D[
 z^2 <= 1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2 , {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 
  4}, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

Or

```
ContourPlot3D[
 z^2 - (1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2), {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 
  4}, Contours -> {0}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

If you want to use `ParametricPlot3D` or `ParametricRegion`, you should change the
$$z^2\leq 1-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3)^2$$
by set $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3=r\cos\theta,z=r\sin\theta$ ,where $0\leq r\leq 1$
and then

$$x=(3+r\cos\theta)\cos\phi,y=(3+r\cos\theta)\sin\phi,z=r\sin\theta$$

```
ParametricRegion[{(3 + r*Cos[θ]) Cos[ϕ], (3 + 
     r*Cos[θ]) Sin[ϕ], 
  r*Sin[θ]}, {{r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕ, 0, 
   2 π}}]
```

We draw the region by set `r=1`.

```
ParametricRegion[{(3 + r*Cos[θ]) Cos[ϕ], (3 + 
       r*Cos[θ]) Sin[ϕ], r*Sin[θ]} /. 
   r -> 1, {{θ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}}] // Region
```

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[z^2 == 1 - (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - 3)^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]`